# How do I switch between Chrome windows while in full screen on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Typically, if I am not in full-screen and the Chrome windows are on the same "virtual window" on my MacBook, I'll use "Cmd + `" which will take me to the next Chrome window open.

Is there a way to do this while in full screen in Chrome? Only change between Chrome windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: not possible.

This is not possible because the way in which Mac Spaces work and the function you're using are incompatible.

Mac Spaces organise content in different Spaces, and when you go fullscreen, that window gets its own Space.

`` cmd + ` `` switches between windows of the same application, but this state is not shared between Spaces.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See other answer: Control + arrow keys left & right

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> is a default keybinding to switch between full-screen applications on MacOS.

As far as I know, there is not a way to limit it to only Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

```
Ctrl key + down arrow key
```

works like a charm for switching between chrome instances on my Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between tabs with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, PlatiB. But the question was re: Windows, not Tabs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

CMD+MAJ+` with a magic keyboard (small)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer that works for my situation, when the full screen mode is for presenting Google Slides (or the rare times I use that Microsoft product that rhymes with "Shower Joint").

What works for me is when going to presentation mode, to use the option for **Presenter View**. In Google I then close the window with speaker notes, and my slides are in display mode, but it's full in the tab, not window.

For display purposes (projector or say screen sharing from video conference app) it shows like full screen, no window or browser elements visible.

Now I can use Command+`to switch between my slides and another browser window where I am in say my video conference software. I like using this so I can jump from slides back to see the video conference chat.